# How to merge two xml files each element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have two xml files which need to be merged into one by using XSLT.  I try to find the solution but without success

file1 =======> xpto.xml

```
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

file2 =======> links.xml

```
<Rows>
    <Row><link>site1</link></Row>
    <Row><link>site2</link></Row>
    <Row><link>site3</link></Row>
    <Row><link>site4</link></Row>
</Rows>
```

The desired merged output: result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Rows   
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
        <link>site1</link>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
        <link>site2</link>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
        <link>site3</link>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
        <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
        <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
        <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
        <link>site4</link>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

=======> merge.xsl (solution what I got, but not what I wanted)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="fileName" select="'links.xml'" />
<xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)" />

<xsl:variable name="updateLinks" select="$updates/Rows/Row" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$updateLinks/*"></xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `<xsl:copy-of select="$updateLinks/*">` to

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$updates//Row[position() = $rowposition]/link">
```

and right under your `<xsl:template match="Row">` add

```
<xsl:variable name="rowposition" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks for you Help!
In this way <xsl:copy-of select="$updates//Row[current()/position()]/link"> give me a error... 
but I change to this: <xsl:copy-of select="$updates//Row[current()=position()]/link"/> 
or to this:  <xsl:copy-of select="$updates//Row[current()=position()]/*"/>

And I still don't suceed

Comment: Thanks again... don't work... and i change to this:
 <xsl:for-each select="."> 
      <xsl:variable name="rowposition" select="position()"/>  
      <xsl:copy-of select="$updates//Row[position()=$rowposition]/link"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
and the better i get result of this:
<Rows>
      <Model>INTEGRA 256 Plus</Model> 
      <Descri>EN-50131 GRADE 3</Descri> 
      <Update>updated: 2014-06-23</Update> 
      <Filesize>1.47 MB</Filesize>
      <link>site1</link>
      ...
      <link>site1</link>
</Rows>

Comment: one more try, sorry, w/o the for-each